# CSS/BOOTSTRAP: making element inside the gird (.container / .row) full (screen) width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a site structure...

```
body
---- main.container
--------- div.row
-------------- div.content
```

inside the content element I inject some content that comes from the CMS..

all works fine... but then there is a demand for a module inside to go full (screen width) so outside the .container - right to the edges

so the content in the end looks like this:

```
body
---- main.container
--------- div.row
-------------- div.content
-------------------- div.col-xs-12.module1
-------------------- div.col-xs-12.module2
-------------------- div.full-width.module3
-------------------- div.col-xs-12.module4
```

now, for .full-width class to achieve actually full screen I went with position: absolute, like this

```
.full-width{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the problem is, that obviously position: absolute removes the element from the flow, and then .module4 appears after .module2, and .module3 over it.

Now, what would be the best way to achieve this correctly?

Things to consider:

- full-width module does not have a fixed height, could be whatever and depends on the content inside
- I don't have the exact margins/padding of the wrapping elements (content/row)...since it could be nested more and the re is no
  guarantee the module is direct child of .row ..... so negative margins would not work

any ideas?

Comment: [Split it into separate `containers`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29073082/3585500)?

Comment: how do you mean? I cant, the wrapper app is already there... the content is injected with the ajax API call, after everything is loaded

Comment: I can't get my head around your question. You want the .full-width to be a 100% too? Just add a class of .col-xs-12 and it will also be full width like the others? With how the Bootstrap works, and the example you've given, it's hard to determine how to do it. Can you drop an example in codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a full width row, you have to use the `.container-fluid` class as specified in the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).

So your site structure should look as:

```
body
---- main
--------- div.container
-------------- div.row
------------------- div.col-xs-12.module1
------------------- div.col-xs-12.module2
--------- div.container-fluid
-------------- div.row
------------------- div.full-width.module3
--------- div.container
-------------- div.row
------------------- div.col-xs-12.module4
```

**EDIT**

If you can't change your HTML structure (IE11+):

```
.full-width {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/tVkNyWJxA6

Comment: If I could change the layout around, I would... but I cannot change nothing above .content (in my example)

Comment: For some reason my row gets always cut in half :/ and first half is left out of the screen ... your example works though in bootply

Comment: Can you reproduce it on bootply or give an access to your website?

Comment: I would have already done it if I could.... sadly it's quite complicated to reproduce and it's a corporate intranet site, so cannot share :(